# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when Vue/Express app deployed on Azure

Tags: azure, vue.js, express, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed an app on Azure using docker-compose. The app has 2 images, the `server` in Express and the `client` in Vue. When I run the app locally it works, but the one on Azure returns the error `\GET http://localhost:2800/citySearch?keyword=m net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED\` each time the client is trying to reach the server.

I believe that since both of them are in the same host `localhost` as host should work.

The `docker-compose`:

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services:
  server:
    image: 1a4devcontain.azurecr.io/amadeus-flight-booking-node-server
    container_name: server-container
    environment:
      AMADEUS_CLIENT_ID: ${AMADEUS_CLIENT_ID:-}
      AMADEUS_CLIENT_SECRET: ${AMADEUS_CLIENT_SECRET:-}
    ports:
      - 2800:2800
  client:
    image: 1a4devcontain.azurecr.io/amadeus-flight-booking-node-client
    container_name: client-container
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      AMADEUS_CLIENT_ID: ${AMADEUS_CLIENT_ID:-}
      AMADEUS_CLIENT_SECRET: ${AMADEUS_CLIENT_SECRET:-}
    depends_on:
      - server
```

The `vue.config.js` :

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
publicPath: "",
runtimeCompiler: true,
devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    port: 8080,
    public: '0.0.0.0:8080'
  }
}
```

The environment variables are all setup properly and one change I did but I think doesn't affect the result is at the `config.vue.js` file to change the public address from:

```
public: '0.0.0.0:8080'
```

to

```
public: 'localhost:8080'
```

Comment: You need to change the server URL in the client code to use the container name instead of localhost. In your case, the server container name is `server-container`, so you should change the URL to http://server-container:2800/citySearch?keyword=m. This should allow the client to communicate with the server container.